# Get Google Analytics session timeout time / session time?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I like to know how different site defined their **Google Analytics session**. Google Analytics have the ability to change the session timeout time from default 30 minutes to what ever the site owner wants. See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871

Is there a way to check the timeout time on the Google Analytics session on a site that I don´t have access the Google Analytics administration. For example get the google analytics session timeout time for paypal.com.

Answer (score 1):

It is not information that can be seen from the website.

It is a value that is used behind the scenes by Google Analytics system, no reference is passed with the interaction hits of the user that use the website.